# Extract ODBC Data Source information

Tags: oracle, odbc

I've gone through ODBC API searching for a function that can extract information of a data source. The closest I found is [SQLDataSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711004(VS.85).aspx) that enumerates all data sources and gives you the DSN name/description.

But specifically I would to extract the TNS service name of an Oracle data source. This property appears in the registry under `ServerName` but I found no way to access it through an API.

Comment: And the question is? What do you want to do, why don't you query the Registry itself then? =)

Comment: I want it to work on Linux too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SQLGetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714560%28VS.85%29.aspx) function, which is typically used by the ODBC Administrator for reading such information is probably the best one to use, as this would be OS independent and implemented by most ODBC Driver Managers on none windows platforms, like  [iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org), [UnixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org)  etc.